# only load the whole jquery stuff if a javascript condition is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I would like to check, if there are more than tho large images on my php-generated forum-page, and only if so, then I would like to load jquery and do *some jquerystuff*.

How can I dynamically load the library only if the condition succeeds?

Comment: With JavaScript. What have you tried so far?

Comment: A [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamically+load+jquery&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&aq=f&oq=dynamically+load+jquery&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.7468j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for `"dynamically load jQuery"` on Google provides your answer to the dynamically loaded part of your question in the very first hit.  The condition part is just an `if` statement.

Comment: What if I don't know how to program JavaScript without jQuery?

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks, I didn't come to that search query. If you put that into an Answer, I can mark this solved.

Comment: _"What if I don't know how to program JavaScript without jQuery?"_. Well, I think that's point of it. You need to at least try and post the code that didn't work. That's how one learns this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function() {
  if (something) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(s);
  }
}());
```

Comment: And how would I check, if jquery isn't already included before?

Comment: if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {